# Why is PrivateRoute preventing my Redux-connected component from re-rendering on store state update?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my `<Content>` component I have:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/monitors" component={MonitorsPage}/>
```

and within `<MonitorsPage>`:

```
<Route path="/monitors/:device_id/live" component={MonitorLive}/>
```

`<MonitorsLive>` uses Redux `connect()` to subscribe to store state changes.

Here is my test `<PrivateRoute>`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function delay(t, v) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t)
  });
}

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  authenticate() {
    delay(1000).then(()=>{
      console.log('AUTHENTICATED');
      this.setState({isLoaded: true})
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authenticate()
  }

  render() {
    const {component: Component, ...rest} = this.props;
    const { isLoaded } = this.state;

    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={
        props => (!isLoaded ? <div>loading...</div> : <Component {...props} />)
      }
      />
    )}}

export default PrivateRoute
```

If I navigate to the `/monitors/:device_id/live` route and refresh browser, the component loads and mounts fine, but fails to re-render on store state changes in this condition. It works fine under a number of other conditions, including:

1. Navigating to the problem route from the `/monitors` route (instead of browser hard-reload) OR
2. `<Content>` and `<MonitorsPage>` both use `<Route>` instead of `<PrivateRoute>` OR
3. `<Content>` and `<MonitorsPage>` both use `<PrivateRoute>` instead of `<Route>` OR
4. `<Content>` uses `<Route>` and `<MonitorsPage>` uses `<PrivateRoute>` OR
5. `this.setState({isLoaded: true})` is executed with no preceding `delay(1000)` in `PrivateRoute`

How can I make this so I can place my `PrivateRoute` as a parent when I know all children `Route`s are also going to be private, without breaking redux?

**UPDATE:** I've modified `MonitorLive` and `MonitorsPage` to include `withRouter()` in the export statement. `Content` already had it. This change doesn't resolve the issue. Example export statement:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MonitorLive))
```

**UPDATE 2:** In addition to the 5 circumstances which eliminate the issue mentioned above, there's this:

If I remove either the line with "text" or `<span>span</span>` from `Content`:

```
class Content extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          text
          <span>span</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.getMonitorLiveValues}>Update State</button>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute
              path="/monitors"
              component={MonitorsPage}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}}
```

**UPDATE 3:**
Demonstrates the issue: https://vvmk3qorq7.codesandbox.io/monitors/ARMS-NVM-P5/live

https://codesandbox.io/s/vvmk3qorq7

Comment: If you change `delay` to regular `setTimeout()` does it still cause rendering errors?

Comment: @DorShinar yes I get the same behavior with setTimeout()

Comment: Does the `MonitorsPage` component re-render after `setState()` with the delay?

Comment: @DorShinar I get the first(initial) render of `MonitorsPage` and `MonitorsLive` after the delay. No re-renders.

Comment: Can you verify that the state is being updated? According to your answers it doesn't strike me as a redux related issue

Comment: You mean the state in `PrivateRoute` (i.e. `isLoaded`)? it's updating and I can replicate the behavior by manually toggling the state in devtools. Any unmounting/remounting triggered through `PrivateRoute` breaks ability to  receive store updates. I think the store is updating based on redux-logger output.

Comment: Could you provide a sandbox replicating your problem? codesandbox, stackblitz, jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by upgrading `react-dom` from 16.3.2 to 16.4.0